odoo 13 error when opening settings: ValueError: Wrong value for res.config.settings.module_procurement_jit: 1
I created a new Odoo server using a backup .zip file from an already working server, including all the addons. The original server is functioning correctly, but the new one is showing this error. The new server works fine without any other issues, but this error persists. Additionally, I selected 'This database is a copy' in the restore popup:
restoreing database
this the error:
2024-12-26 19:07:22,609 818 ERROR test odoo.http: Exception during JSON request handling.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 624, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 310, in _handle_exception
    raise pycompat.reraise(type(exception), exception, sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/odoo/odoo/tools/pycompat.py", line 14, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 669, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 350, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/odoo/odoo/service/model.py", line 94, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 339, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 915, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 515, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1342, in call_kw
    return self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
  File "/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1334, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 390, in call_kw
    result = _call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 377, in _call_kw_multi
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 6277, in onchange
    record[name] = value
  File "/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 5777, in __setitem__
    return self._fields[key].__set__(self, value)
  File "/odoo/odoo/fields.py", line 1116, in __set__
    self.write(new_records, value)
  File "/odoo/odoo/fields.py", line 987, in write
    cache_value = self.convert_to_cache(value, records)
  File "/odoo/odoo/fields.py", line 2299, in convert_to_cache
    raise ValueError("Wrong value for %s: %r" % (self, value))
ValueError: Wrong value for res.config.settings.module_procurement_jit: 1

error when opening settings in odoo

Maybe your value is supposed to be string but you are getting integer(may be you are getting id of the record instead of name).

Try to upgrade the related modules: stock... Otherwise, have a look to similar error cases: https://www.odoo.com/fi_FI/forum/apua-1/i-m-getting-an-error-help-in-general-settings-please-183066, https://www.odoo.com/fr_FR/forum/aide-1/migration-error-in-settings-value-res-config-settings-chart-template-s-262492

The error indicates that an invalid value (1) was assigned to the module_procurement_jit setting, likely due to a misconfiguration or missing module.
